# AngularJS - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

Just trying to read a URL and I get the following error.

"Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]"

Any ideas?

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{catalog}}
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>


var app = angular.module('app', ['jsonService']);

angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93930/catalog.json');
});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, JsonService){
  JsonService.get(function(data){
    $scope.catalog = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `ngResource` script to your page

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

2. Create `jsonService`before `app` module
3. Correct your `catalog.json` file - Angular cannot parse it. Use http://jsonlint.com/ for validating your `json`

   `Error: Parse error on line 2:
   [
     {
       title: "Selmer S2000
   ----------^
   Expecting 'STRING', '}'`

Code is here [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/duhahunofi/edit?html,js)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to following. You need to create module 'jsonService', before you use it in your app.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      {{catalog}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
      return $resource('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93930/catalog.json');
    });

    var app = angular.module('app', ['jsonService']);

    app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, JsonService){
      JsonService.get(function(data){
        $scope.catalog = data;
      });
    });
```