# Angulrjs - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, socket.io

I have client-server application and I encountered this error: "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]".
I searched and I found many answers but non of them fixed the problem..
Here is my client code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [
  'btford.socket-io', 'ngRoute'
]).
factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
  var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

  mySocket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: myIoSocket
  });

  return mySocket;
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,$route, mySocket) {
 $scope.func = function(){
  mySocket.emit('add user', "aaa");
 };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head data-ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>     
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular-route.js"></script>
 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Socket.IO Chat Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body ng-init="func()" data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul class="pages">
    <li class="chat page">
        <div class="chatArea">
            <ul class="messages"></ul>
        </div>
        <input class="inputMessage" placeholder="Type here..."/>
    </li>
    <li class="login page">
        <div class="form">
            <h3 class="title">What's your nickname?</h3>
            <input class="usernameInput" type="text" maxlength="14" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script><!----------------------------------------->
<script src="main2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what could fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Uncaught Error: \[$injector:modulerr\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921623/angularjs-uncaught-error-injectormodulerr)

Comment: In your factory, you are using io.connect. Where is the dependency of io?

Comment: Can you paste the error you see in the console?

Answer (score 1):

actually you are using **data-ng-app="myApp"** in **head tag.so that module is available only inside head tag.**

you may try to  declare in **html** tag. and then try..

hope u get result...

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

this can be fix using following techniques

1. first you need to move ng-app like that
   `<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">`
2. second is please remove the 'btford.socket-io' from your module if you not want to use it, like that

   ```
      angular.module('myApp', [
         'ngRoute'
      ])
   ```
3. If you not want to use *btford.socket-io* then download its this plugin path and
   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-socket-io/0.7.0/socket.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the main `angular-socket-io/socket.js` file that is used to load the `btford.socket-io` module. Everything should work once you include that! One other note, you may want to only load 1 jQuery library, they're pretty large and can hurt load time [Just personal suggestion :) ].

Resouce: [angular-socket-io : Install](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io#install)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting [$injector:modulerr] error means it could be due to modules used in you app is not loaded.

Try loading script socket.io.js in the head section, same as of angular scripts.